# PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, drupal, pdo

Keep getting error message when running this code. The stored procedure takes two values, begindate and endate. It is processed from a form and upon submit, the values will be stored in the startdatevalue and enddatevalue.

The error is as described in the title.

> PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given

The only other information which could be of interest is that this is a custom module in drupal.

```
$startdatevalue = "03/25/2015";
$enddatevalue = "04/02/2015";

print_r($startdatevalue." and ".$enddatevalue);



$conn = Database::getConnection(); //get connection

$saved_class = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('PDOStatement'));

$statement_siteUsage = $conn->prepare("Call sps_SiteUsageStatistics(?,?)"); //stored procedure to be run


$op_status = $statement->bindParam(1, $startdatevalue, PDO::PARAM_STR);//| PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT
$op_status = $statement->bindParam(2, $enddatevalue, PDO::PARAM_STR);// | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT

$exec_result = $statement_siteUsage->execute();
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, $saved_class);

//$startdatevalue = $_POST["begindate"];
//$enddatevalue = $_POST["enddate"];

$sql_siteUsage = $exec_result;

$result = db_query($sql_siteUsage);
$record = fetchAll();
```

Comment: How come the error states you included `2` parameters when there is `$statement_siteUsage->execute();`? Are you showing the actual code?

Comment: is it still april fools? theres no usage of `->execute()` inside the question which has 2 parameters

Comment: @Ghost if we were all stuck in a *time warp*, sure ;-) another *Stack egg?* Cracks me up.

Comment: this is the execute line $exec_result = $statement_siteUsage->execute();

Comment: this is the stored proc line $statement_siteUsage = $conn->prepare("Call sps_SiteUsageStatistics(?,?)"); and it really does work with startdate and endate in the database

Comment: Should $op_status = $statement->bindParam(1, $startdatevalue, PDO::PARAM_STR); be $op_status = $statement_siteUsage->bindParam(1, $startdatevalue, PDO::PARAM_STR); ?